# How to handle both ipv4 and ipv6 client request

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I am new to socket programming, My use case is to handle client request for both ipv4 and ipv6. Right now ipv4 is working fine but not able to use  ipv6 Ip.

// Run Server
Python server.py -i '' -p 2010

Note: '' Means I want to listen to the client at both addresses.
server.py

```
tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServer.bind((self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_Port))
tcpServer.listen(4)

while True:
    print "Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients..."
    (conn, (ip, port)) =  tcpServer.accept()
    print("Client connected: {}:{}".format(ip, port))
```

client.py

```
host = "::1" 
port = 2010


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
s.connect((host, port))

print "Non Secure ipv6 authentication"
while True:
    s.send("Hello, world!\n")
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and worked for me, posting for others.

```
bindsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
bindsocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 0)
addr = [addr for addr in socket.getaddrinfo(self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_Port,
                                            socket.AF_INET6, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)]

try:
    bindsocket.bind((addr[0][-1]))
except socket.error as e:
    print str(e)
bindsocket.listen(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is trying to connect an IPv6 client to an IPv4 server.  That will not work.  You will need an IPv6 server.

Some platforms support **dual-stack** sockets, which can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 client connections, provided both protocols are installed in the OS. Basically, you create an `AF_INET6` socket, disable the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option on it, and `bind()` it to the IPv6 `in6addr_any` wildcard (`”::”`) for listening.  Any IPv4 client that is accepted will report an [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](http://mars.tekkom.dk/w/index.php/IPv4-Mapped_IPv6_Address) as its remote IP address.

On platforms that do not support dual-stack sockets, you have no choice but to simply create separate `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` sockets for listening.

Comment: Yes, my system supports both ipv6 and ipv4.

Comment: @DeepakMourya just because a system supports both protocols doesn’t guarantee it also supports dual-stack sockets. You need to check the documentation for the platform(s) you are running your server code on.

Comment: Hi yes supports just confirm from the internal team.